# How is the affine coordinate ring of an affine variety $\mathscr{O}_X(X)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

From Goertz and Wedhorn,

> [image]

I do not follow the last sentence. As I understand it $\Gamma(X)$ is defined as $k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I(X)$, and $\mathscr{O}_X(U)$ for $U\subseteq X$ is defined as rational functions in $\text{Frac}\left(\Gamma(X)\right)$ whose denominators do not vanish on $U$. One is a polynomial ring and the other is its fraction field. How can they be equal for an affine variety $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ring $\mathscr{O}_X(U)$ is *not* defined as the fraction field of $\Gamma(X)$.  Rather, as you say, it is the *subring* of the fraction field consisting of fractions whose denominators do not vanish on $U$.  It's still not obvious that $\mathscr{O}_X(X)$ would be $\Gamma(X)$, but this is proved earlier in the book, in Proposition 1.40 (when you unravel what the statement means, it is basically a restatement of the Nullstellensatz).

Comment: I think I get it. $\mathscr{O}_X(D(f)) = \Gamma(X)_f$. If $X = D(\mathfrak{a})$ then $\mathfrak{a} = k^\times$. Intuitively speaking, the only rational functions defined everywhere are those with trivial denominators—is this right? (Are we assuming that $k$ is algebraically closed? Also, is it crucial that $X$ is irreducible?)

Comment: I don't follow your notation, but the denominators don't have to be constants--they just have to be units in the ring $\Gamma(X)$.  For instance, if $X$ is defined by the curve $xy-1$ in the plane, then the coordinate functions $x$ and $y$ are units (they are each other's inverses).  The field $k$ is assumed to be algebraically closed, and the book's definition of $\mathscr{O}_X$ only makes sense if $X$ is irreducible (thought it is possible to define it for reducible algebraic sets as well).